# IPhone sdk: Internationalization doesnt works

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, internationalization

Recently I have made intenationalization support for my project.
But there occurs strange thing - when I'm running my application both on the device and emulator shows only 'default' language.

I've done following things:

> - Used NSLocalizedString everywhere
> - added InfoPlist.strings (another language)

May be I'm missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store your localized strings in Localizable.strings. Localized InfoPlist.strings is used to change the name of your app for example.